# asp.net: Type '' is not defined. File is there, reference is there, works fine locally, but

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

There has GOT to be something REALLY simple I am missing here.

Here's my web page code:

```
Imports DataUtil
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim db = New DataUtil.DataUtil("xxxx")
        Response.Write("hi")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Pretty simple, right?  I have a file (`DataUtil.dll`) in the `bin` folder. The file is referenced properly and in fact this WebApp runs just fine on my computer. The web page comes up and I see the word "hi" as expected.

BUT... when I publish this to my *GoDaddy* host, this is what I get:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'DataUtil.DataUtil' is not
>   defined. Source File:
>   D:\Hosting\000000000\html\testsite\Default.aspx.vb  Line: 6

This is Line 6:

```
Dim db = New DataUtil.DataUtil("xxxx")
```

I check and see that the `DataUtil.dll` file is in the bin directory as expected.

What stupid, simple thing am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't be registered as well via regsvr ?

Comment: .net does not require the registration of dll's provided they are in a directory that is known or seen by the application.  I even moved the dll to the working directory and that did not work either.